# SQL - Select only when all data done

Tags: sql, algorithm, select

So, I have data in the one-to-many table:

```
id          user_id      type      status
1           1            A         Done
2           1            B         Done
3           1            C         Done
4           1            D         Ready
5           2            A         Done
6           2            B         Ready
7           2            C         Done
8           2            D         Ready
```

What's possible way to select all of D when status `Ready` and all of A,B,C wth the same `user_id`  status is  `Done`

If one of A, B, C with the same `user_id` status is not 'Done', then it is not selected.

I'm stuck on the `WHERE` function

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 'D' and status = 'Ready' and (A,B,C with the same user_id  is Done)
```

Comment: There is no `type = 'D'` in your table. `D2` is not the same as `D`.

Comment: Did you mean `type LIKE 'D%'`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have updated the table that I meant.

Comment: Has nothing to do with php ??!!

Comment: @mostav I have tried it. But the algorithm I made was inefficient because of too many iterations and there were thousands of data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t1
WHERE type = 'D'
AND status = 'Ready'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table AS t2
    WHERE type IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
    AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND status != 'Done'
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen an opportunity to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select id, user_id, type, status
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        max(case when type <> 'D' and status <> 'Done' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by user_id) flag
    from mytable t
) t
where type = 'D' and status = 'Ready' and flag = 0
```